# Getting Dell M6500 to work with Apple 30 inch display

Tags: dell-precision

I have a Dell M6500 laptop and I can't get it to work with my 30" Apple Cinema display. I have tried every combination imaginable but it just doesn't work. I have the ATI Firepro 7820 with 1GB memory and 16GB RAM. Has anyone been able to get this to work?

Comment: Wow...that's quite a laptop. Is there a key you have to press to get the output onto the Mac display? Function and something else? Just throwing the basic ones out there. Or if you're on Windows 7 press Windows Key and P.

Comment: Yes, I've tried Windows - P (projector mode).. Anyway, its not such an awesome laptop, as it only has VGA out! :(

Comment: Are you using a dual link DVI cable? You need to with any 30 inch high resolution monitor.

Comment: The Mac 30" monitor comes with its own cable built in, so you don't get a choice